# Unable to get login to work using scala with Play Framework

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I am trying to create login functionality for a website built in the play framework. When credentials of an existing user is entered into the html view, and the submit (login) button is clicked the login page doesn't do anything.

LoginController:

```
 class LoginController @Inject() extends Controller {

    def login(Email:String, password:String): Boolean = {
      val user = CustomerLogin.findCustomer(Email).get
      var status:Boolean = false
      if(user.password == password) {
        //log the user in
        status = true
      }  else {
        status = false
      }
      status
    }


  def index = Action {
    implicit request =>
      Ok(views.html.loginOurs(LoginForm))
  }


  private val LoginForm: Form[CustomerLogin] = Form(mapping(
    "Email" -> nonEmptyText,
    "password" -> nonEmptyText)(CustomerLogin.apply)(CustomerLogin.unapply))


  def save = Action {
    implicit  request =>
      val newLoginForm = LoginForm.bindFromRequest()
      newLoginForm.fold(hasErrors = {
        form =>
          Redirect(routes.LoginController.index()).flashing(Flash(form.data) +
            ("error" -> Messages("validation.errors")))
      }, success = {
        newLogin =>
          Redirect(routes.HomeController.home()).flashing("success" -> Messages("customers.new.success", newLogin.Email))}
      )
  }


  def newLogin = Action {
    implicit request =>
      val form = if(request2flash.get("error").isDefined)
        LoginForm.bind(request2flash.data)
      else
        LoginForm
      Ok(views.html.loginOurs(form))
  }


}
```

loginOurs.scala.html (some)

```
<div id="content">

    @main(Messages("login.form")) {
    <h2>@Messages("login form")</h2>
    @helper.form(action = routes.LoginController.save) {
    <fieldset>
        <legend>
            @Messages("customer.details", Messages("customer.new"))
        </legend>
        @helper.inputText(LoginForm("Email"))
        @helper.inputText(LoginForm("Password"))
    </fieldset>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" class="btn-primary" value='@Messages("submit")'>
    </p>
    }
    }
</div>
```

Routes (Login stuff only)

```
GET     /login                   controllers.LoginController.newLogin

POST    /login                   controllers.LoginController.save

GET    /login/:Email             controllers.LoginController.login3(Email:String)

GET     /login                      controllers.HomeController.confirm(Email:String)
```

Any help given would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks
Jackie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful of the caps of Email and Password, I think there is a mismatch in

```
 @helper.inputText(LoginForm("Email"))
 @helper.inputText(LoginForm("Password"))
```

and

```
 private val LoginForm: Form[CustomerLogin] = Form(mapping(
    "Email" -> nonEmptyText,
    "password" -> nonEmptyText)(CustomerLogin.apply)(CustomerLogin.unapply))
```